# Likelihood Ratio and Neyman-Pearson factorization theorem

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm looking at a family of distributions given by $P = \{P_{\theta} \quad | \quad \theta \in \{0,1\} \}$. I'm trying to prove that

$$T(x) = \frac{p_{1}(x)}{p_{0}(x)}$$

(i. e. the likelihood ratio) is a sufficient statistic for $\theta$.

To do so, I have to show that

$$p(x, \theta) = g_{\theta}(T(x))h(x)$$.

I know that if $\theta = 0$, $p(x, 0) = p_{0}(x)$ and $p(x,1)=p_{1}(x)$ for $\theta = 1$.

I'm having trouble finding functions $g$ and $h$ that produce this. My initial idea was to define $h(x) = 1$ and $g_{\theta}((T(x)) = T(x)p_{0}(x)$ for $\theta = 1$ and  $g_{\theta}((T(x)) = T^{-1}(x)p_{1}(x)$ for $\theta = 0$. The problem with this is that g does not exclusively depend on $x$ through $T(x)$ if I define it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $h(x)=p(x,0)$, $g(T(x),0)=1$ and $g(T(x),1)=T(x)$.

Comment: I just figured that out myself. Turns out it was easier than I thought :-)